# Reduce two consecutive character to just one and remove if that character is standalone

Tags: regular-expression

Converting odt to markdown produces `\` around special characters. So I need to change `\\` to `\` and remove if `\` is standalone.

Sample text:

```
* \[\] match any of the character specified within \[\], use \[^\] to invert the selection
* \\W opposite of \\w i.e short cut for \[^a-zA-Z0-9\_\]
* \\w match alphabets (both upper & lower cases), numbers and \_ i.e short cut for \[a-zA-Z0-9\_\]
```

Expected output:

```
* [] match any of the character specified within [], use [^] to invert the selection
* \W opposite of \w i.e short cut for [^a-zA-Z0-9_]
* \w match alphabets (both upper & lower cases), numbers and _ i.e short cut for [a-zA-Z0-9_]
```

On using `:% s/\v([^\\])\\([^\\])/\1\2/g` I get this:

```
* [\] match any of the character specified within [\], use [^] to invert the selection
* \\W opposite of \\w i.e short cut for [^a-zA-Z0-9_\]
* \\w match alphabets (both upper & lower cases), numbers and _ i.e short cut for [a-zA-Z0-9_\]
```

So I use the substitution again to take care of sequences like `\[\]` followed by `:% s/\\\\/\\/g` to get the desired final output. Is there is a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
:%s/\\\?\zs\\//g
```

Here the first `\\\?\zs` is used to ignore the first `\` if there are two of them. See `:h \?` and `:h \zs` for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Alternate solution (based on a comment I received for this question, but was deleted before I could reply)

```
:%s/\v(\\?)\\/\1/g
```

This is useful as I can now use `sed` also (couldn't find equivalent of `\zs` in sed):

```
sed -r 's/(\\?)\\/\1/g'
```

and `\K` seems equivalent of `\zs` in `Perl` (saw it while going through this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13466/can-grep-output-only-specified-groupings-that-match))

```
s/\\?\K\\//g
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are over-complicating your original regex by trying to trap the character *before* the backslash. The following seems to work on your sample text. You will need to expand the [...] expression to include all special characters you may come across.

```
:%s!\v\\([][\_])!\1!g
```

`[][\_]` is a single entity comprising ] (which has to come first) and [,\,_ but you probably already knew that.

Comment: yeah, the one I posted in question was complicated and couldn't handle many cases..  yours does indeed work very well for sample text I gave, however it won't catch all cases, like `\* \#` etc.. thanks for different approach, something new to learn :)